# Thread-Safe or Non-Thread-Safe PHP Extension for Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am wanting to install the MongoDB PHP extension for Windows for my Dev server to play around with it.

Looking at the PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows for "Installing on Windows" it has a list of Downloads, they basically list `Non-Thread-Safe Mongo extension` and `Thread-Safe Mongo extension`

Without getting too technical, which version should I use, or more importantly, what would be used to decide which version to use?

I will only be using this Windows version on my Dev server, if I ever use MongoDB in a live environment it will likely be ran on a Linux box.  If it matters my Dev server is running Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which to install really depends on just what you will be working on and in the vast majority of cases it really doesn't matter. However, if you believe the final target will be a Linux box I strongly recommend you develop on that platform from the start. This is most easily achieved by using Virtualbox, or similar and running the Linux distro of your choice. Developing on a different platform to the target has a nasty track record of resulting in bugs.

Comment: Well, "resulting in *more bugs than otherwise*," to be pedantic and technical about it.

Comment: @HoplessN00b, fair call. :)